# Is there a graphical way to connect buttons to events in Android Studio?

Tags: android, user-interface, android-studio

In Xcode, we can drag a button to the controller file and it builds the shell of the action function for you to implement. Is there a way to this Android Studio? If not, any indication that they might add this feature in the future? It seems much more convenient than declaring a button and then using findViewById all programmatically.

Thank you.

Comment: No. Android studio still doesn't has this option.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat, using Android Studio in the properties you can specify the method you want run in the onClick property. You can read a little more about it here

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Overview_and_Android_Studio_Example_of_Android_Event_Handling

You will need to actually create the method in your activity and have it use the appropriate method signature, however you will not need to rely on findViewById.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible but why do you want that?
I think it is easier to create a class (maybe inner class) that implements the listener interface and then set the instace of this class as listener to your view. You have to create the listener anyway so I think you will not save time doing it with android studios GUI.